# Unable to run Jupyter Notebook on macOS (import error)

Tags: macos, jupyter-notebook, importerror

I am unable to run Jupyter Notebook. I used to be able to launch it by typing that into Terminal and running it. After encountering the 500: Internal Error, I tried updating some files using commands I found on another page. Now when I do try to run it, I encounter this error:

> dlopen(/Users/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/rpds/rpds.cpython-39-darwin.so,
> 0x0002): tried:
> '/Users/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/rpds/rpds.cpython-39-darwin.so'
> (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need
> 'x86_64')),
> '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/rpds/rpds.cpython-39-darwin.so'
> (no such file),
> '/Users//Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/rpds/rpds.cpython-39-darwin.so'
> (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need
> 'x86_64'))

I've tried uninstalling Jupyter, and reinstalling it in case there was an issue with some files. Jupyter lab prints the same error. It only works when i open it through anaconda

Comment: I love how it autocorrected macOS to McDonald's. Took me a while.

Comment: Before running commands you find on the Internet, you need to make sure whether the instructions apply to your system.   Which version (and platform) of Python did you install?

Comment: Following on what Ewokx said, it looks like you installed arm64 and need x86_64 or vice versa. One way is to let a package management system handle this for you. Lots of people like brew on Mac. Personally, I'd suggest [the Anaconda Distribution](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/index.html) that handles setting things up more easily for you and comes with more advanced features you'll want as you continue to use Python & Jupyter, namely environments. Then you launch Jupyter from within the Anaconda Navigator. And for anything with a conda recipe, install with that. `pip` as fallback.